# MS Project 2010 Base calendar is ignored

Tags: calendar, microsoft-project-2010

I'm using Project 2010 with a project base calendar that has been loaded with exceptions for company holidays. However, when I add tasks to it and resource load them, it is ignoring the base calendar and spreading hours against a holiday exception as a working day in the Gantt.

This problem is fixed if I assign the project base calendar to either the task or the resource but by default shouldn't Project use the base calendar for all tasks and resources when a specific calendar is NOT assigned to that task or resource?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't given your resources the same calendar. Are they still using "Standard" whilst you have put the company holidays into a base calendar of its own?

If this is the case, resource availability in terms of generic company-wide holidays will be calculated from the "Standard" base calendar whilst the project will be working with its own base calendar.

When you set up a base calendar for a project, which you should always do, you should do it first and then whenever you add a resource to the project, make sure each one is also using the same base calendar.